# How to get logged in users membership plan in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions, woocommerce-memberships

Currently I am working on membership site where their are two types of membership

1) Free Membership
2) Premium membership

Based on these membership I want to change content of any pages
For this I am using WooCommerce, WooCommerce Subscription and WooCommerce Membership.So Please tell me how I can get the membership plan after user logged to its account.

Thanks
Mayank

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Woocommerce subscriptions plugin has a class **WC_Subscriptions_Manager** that has a static function **get_users_subscriptions**. This function returns array containing user's subscriptions. So please use following code:

```
<?php
      WC_Subscriptions_Manager::get_users_subscriptions(get_current_user_id());  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 2.0, use the function wcs_get_users_subscriptions(). It returns WC_Subscription[].

Answer (score 0):

The wording of the question technically asks about Memberships, not Subscriptions.

If you're actually talking about the [Woo Memberships](https://woo.com/products/woocommerce-memberships/) plugin, then you will want this.

Memberships are usually created via a corresponding Subscription, but they can also be created manually, so be careful not to treat the two things as the same if a Subscription is not what you're intending to check for.

```
function myslug_current_user_has_membership( $membership_slug ) {
    $has_membership = false;
    if ( class_exists( 'WC_Memberships_User_Memberships' ) ) {
        $memberships      = new WC_Memberships_User_Memberships();
        $user_memberships = $memberships->get_user_memberships( get_current_user_id() );
        foreach ( $user_memberships as $membership ) {
            $membership_plan = wc_memberships_get_membership_plan( $membership->plan_id );
            if ( $membership_slug === $membership_plan->slug ) {
                $has_membership = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $has_membership;
}

// example usage
if ( myslug_current_user_has_membership( 'premium-membership' ) ) {
    echo 'this is a premium membership!';
}
```